# RegEx BackReference to Match Different Values

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a regex that I use to match Expression of the form `(val1 operator val2)`

This regex looks like :

```
(\(\s*([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|[0-9]+|\'.*\'|\[.*\])\s*(ni|in|\*|\/|\+|\-|==|!=|>|>=|<|<=)\s*([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|[0-9]+|\'.*\'|\[.*\])\s*\))
```

Which is actually good and matches what I want as you can see [here in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ9eW4/1)

BUT :D (here comes the butter)

I want to optimise the regex itself by making it more readable and "Compact". I searched on how to do that and I found something called back-reference, in which you can name your capturing groups and then reference them later as such:

```
(\(\s*(?P<Val>[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|[0-9]+|\'.*\'|\[.*\])\s*(ni|in|\*|\/|\+|\-|==|!=|>|>=|<|<=)\s*(\g{Val})\s*\))
```

where I named the group that captures the left side of the expression `Val` and later I referenced it as `(\g{Val})`, now the **problem** is that this expression as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/vZ5sW2/2) only case where left side of the expression is exactly the same as right side! e.g. `(a==a)` or `(1==1)` and does not match expressions such as `(a==b)`!

Now the question is: is there a way to reference the pattern instead of the matched value?!

Comment: In PCRE, that should be `(?&Val)`, not `\g{Val}`. What is your regex engine?

Comment: I am using PHP sorry I forgot to tag it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `\g{N}` is equivalent to `\1`, that is, a *backreference* that matches the same *value*, not the pattern, that the corresponding capturing group matched. This syntax is a bit more flexible though, since you can define the capture groups that are *relative* to the current group by using `-` before the number (i.e. `\g{-2}`, `(\p{L})(\d)\g{-2}` will match `a1a`).

The PCRE engine allows [**subroutine calls**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to recurse subpatterns. To repeat the pattern of Group 1, use `(?1)`, and `(?&Val)` to recurse the pattern of the named group `Val`.

Also, you may use character classes to match single characters, and consider using `?` quantifier to make parts of the regex optional:

```
(\(\s*(?P<Val>[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|[0-9]+|\'.*\'|\[.*\])\s*(ni|in|[*\/+-]|[=!><]=|[><])\s*((?&Val))\s*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nF6eI0/2)

Note that `\'.*\'` and `\[.*\]` can match too much, consider replacing with `\'[^\']*\'` and `\[[^][]*\]`.

Comment: Note that the `(?&Val)` must be wrapped into a separate capturing group to also capture a value, hence `((?&Val))`.

Comment: and thanks for the advice I will change the array and string matchers :) +1

Comment: btw what if I want to match recursive expressions like `((a+1)==(b*5))` .. in this case my expression will match only two expressions `(a+1)` and `(b*5)` how can I adjust it to match the whole expression !?

Comment: If you apply recursion, you will lose captures inside it. Do you really want it? Use a basic expression to match all nested parentheses with `/\((?>[^()]++|(?R))*\)/` and then parse each with your expression. Or get rid of all this fancy stuff then, use [`/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|[0-9]+|\'[^\']*\'|\[[^][]*\]/`](https://regex101.com/r/wR6oX9/1).

Comment: yes please, I want to know this also out of curiosity :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121145/discussion-between-ahmad-hajjar-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1):

What language/application are you using this regular expression in?
If you have the option you can specify the different parts as named variables and then build the final regular expression by combining them.

```
val = "([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*|[0-9]+|\'.*\'|\[.*\])"
op = "(ni|in|\*|\/|\+|\-|==|!=|>|>=|<|<=)"
exp = "(\(" .. val .. "\s*" .. op .. "\s*" .. val .. "\))"
```

Comment: I am doing this actually but I am asking out of curiosity :D