# Regex: Can I name a pattern/group to condense code when reusing the pattern/group?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to name or reference a grouped pattern for reuse without enforcing a similar match across this pattern to shorten my regex.

I'm sure there are examples with more obvious benefit to doing something like this, but let's say I want to match something like a string composed of six 2-digit hex numbers separated by colons, such as `38:f8:b7:90:45:92`.

The pattern I came up with for this is `(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}`

`[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}` is used to represent a 2-digit hex number, which I'll call the hex pattern. Instead of repeating this a second time after the colon, I'd like a way to name this or something so I can shorten my regex.

I've already tried `(?:(?<x>[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}):){5}\k<x>` but rather than  being the original hex pattern I made, it seems to only match with the last match the hex pattern found. For example, running this regex on `38:f8:b7:90:45:92` will basically turn the pattern into `([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}):){5}45` since 45 is the last match the original hex pattern found.

Therefore only something like `00:18:12:c1:5a:5a`, where the last two 2-digit numbers are the same, will match.

Is there a way to name a pattern for complete reuse?

Comment: If it is pcre for example, you could recurse the first subpattern `(?:([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}):){5}(?1)` or by name `(?:(?<x>[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}):){5}(?&x)`

Comment: [Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794603/reuse-part-of-a-regex-pattern), [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204214), [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992457), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466549).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If supported, you could make use of [repeating the subpattern](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines)

That might look like:

```
(?:([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}):){5}(?1)
   ^                    ^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SoBjay/2)

Or by name:

```
(?:(?<x>[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}):){5}(?&x)
   ^^^^^                    ^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SoBjay/1)

Comment: That first one looks shorter but that second answer is exactly what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. It is not shorter, but you might also turn it around by defining the group first `(?<x>[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})(?::(?&x)){5}`