# Use named regex groups to shorten the pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use named groups in regex to reduce the size of the regex.  However, even in its simplest form and after clearing all the 'noise', I cannot get it to work.

When I try the example in the documentation of regex101 it works.

```
/(?<first>a+) and again (\k<first>)/
```

here is my simplest example and it's not working.

```regex
(?<months>December)|^(next)\s(\k<months>)
```

here is the input "next" is not matching.

```regex
next December
December 2020
```

I would expect "next December" to match for the first row but instead, it's only matching "December" in both rows.

you can find the regex here https://regex101.com/r/aEgfe8/3/

The documentation only mentions that the named group has to be on the left.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `(?P>months)` or `(?P>months)` instead of `\k<months>`:

```
(?<months>December)|^(next)\s((?&months))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^ 
(?<months>December)|^(next)\s((?P>months))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jqK1Mj/1)

The `\k<first>` is a named backreference that only matches a matched text. Since `(?<months>December)` is in another branch and did not match, the backreference is empty.

To recurse, *reuse*, part of patterns in one regex you need to use regex named subroutines, and the syntax is `(?&NAME)`.

See more details at [Regular Expression Subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html):

> Perl uses `(?1)` to call a numbered group, `(?+1)` to call the next group, `(?-1)` to call the preceding group, and `(?&name)` to call a named group. You can use all of these to reference the same group. `(?+1)(?'name'[abc])(?1)(?-1)(?&name)` matches a string that is five letters long and consists only of the first.

**In C#**, regex subroutines are not supported. Just repeat the subpattern:

```
var rep = "December";
var ThePattern = $@"(?<months>{rep})|^(next)\s({rep})";
```

The [pattern will look like](https://ideone.com/TsIq9t) `(?<months>December)|^(next)\s(December)`.

**Related links to questions about reusing part of a regex**:

- [python](/questions/tagged/python): [Reuse part of a Regex pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794603/reuse-part-of-a-regex-pattern)
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23): [RegEx - reusing subexpressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204214/regex-reusing-subexpressions)
- [php](/questions/tagged/php) [RegEx BackReference to Match Different Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992457/regex-backreference-to-match-different-values/38992601#38992601)
            [Is it possible to define a pattern and reuse it to capture multiple groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878948/is-it-possible-to-define-a-pattern-and-reuse-it-to-capture-multiple-groups)
- [java](/questions/tagged/java): [Regex reuse a pattern to capture multiple groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466549/regex-reuse-a-pattern-to-capture-multiple-groups)
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript): [Reuse capturing group pattern in JS regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553431/3832970)

Comment: Thank you @wiktor-stribiżew, that definitely helps.  Unfortunately, that syntax doesn't work in C#. any idea?

Comment: @SafwanHak Why didn't you add the right tag from the start? .NET does not support recursion/regex subroutines at all.

Comment: I thought it's my misunderstanding of regex and my misuse of \k.  only after your suggestion, the C# issue came up.