# How to backreference group when using or in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am using TypeScript and I want to remove all the comments from the code using regex. Here's my sample code:

```
// this is awesome code
const a =1

// this is nice
const b = 2 // oh great


  // with some indentation
const x = 99
```

I want to preserve the new lines as it is and want to remove all the lines so final output should look like the below:

```
const a =1

const b = 2


const x = 99
```

To achieve above I have to write regex: `^( *\/\/.*)\n|( *\/\/.*)`

The question is how can I backreference the first group after or `|` condition? I can't do `^( *\/\/.*)\n|(\1)`.

> *P.S. I am using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for testing*

Thanks.

Comment: What regex tool are you using?

Comment: You want `\g<1>`/`(?1)`, right? In order not to repeat a pattern part? See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992457/regex-backreference-to-match-different-values/38992601#38992601).

Comment: You could try `\t*\/\/\t*[^\n]+`

Comment: @anubhava https://regex101.com/ for testing and I am using JS.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, using \g<1> works but it doesn't support JS ): Maybe I should update the question mentioning JS

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Your regex don't include spaces before comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```bash
^[ \t]*\/\/.*\r?\n|[ \t]*\/\/.*
```

And replace with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cc3eqA/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[ \t]*`: Match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\/\/`: Match `//`
- `.*`: Match everything till end of line
- `\r?\n`: Match optional carriage return followed by line feed character
- `|`: OR
- `[ \t]*`: Match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\/\/`: Match `//`
- `.*`: Match everything till end of line

Comment: Almost there. But this regex removes the two lines between `const b` and `const x`. We just got single line between both `const`.

Comment: Moreover, the question is regarding backreferencing groups with or.

Comment: check my updated answer that preserves line breaks between `const b` and `const x`. You don't need to back-reference any groups since you just intend to remove matched parts.

Comment: btw if you're using Javascript you may also use this regex: `[ \t]*\/\/.*(?:(?<=^[ \t]*\/\/.*)\r?\n)?`

Comment: @JDSolanki: If I understand you correctly you wanted to avoid repeating `[ \t]*\/\/.*` on both sides of `|`. This is not back-reference. A back-reference matches same captured value but it doesn't repeat same regex subpattern. That feature is available in PCRE but not in Javascript. btw in php/PCRE this regex can be simplified to: `(^)?[ \t]*\/\/.*(?(1)\r?\n)`

Comment: Hi @anubhava. I have a few questions if you don't mind. 1) If this is not called backreference then what it is called? 2) Can you please update your answer to explain JS regex you mentioned in the above comment? 3) Assume if I have `hello123-123` and I have regex `(hello)(123)-(\2)` then I can omit to repeat the second group using `\2` in JS so why it doesn't support with or? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can use it here because `123` is same value. However if you want to match `hello123-789` then you cannot use: `(hello)(\d+)-(\2)`